# python django models int() argument must be a string a bytes-like object or a number not a datetime

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, models

In Django models, I'm trying to create two tables: `Job` and `Images`, and I'm trying to relate the image table to the jobs table through the job_id. But every time I migrate, I get the following error:

*int() argument must be a string a bytes-like object or a number not a datetime*

My code below:

```
from Django.db import models

class Job(models.Model):
    job_id = models.IntegerField(default=1, primary_key=True)
    summary = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/')

class Images(models.Model):
    image_id = models.IntegerField(default=1, primary_key=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    job_id = models.ForeignKey(Job, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: The reason for the error you are getting is not in the code you posted. Beside that, you should fix your naming: Why should a model ever have a plural name (Images), why create manuell pk fields when django takes care of that for you, why call a fk field `job_id` when accessing the field returns a `Job` instance, not an id, and django provides the id by appending `_id` implicitly?

Comment: Please post the error trackback here.

Comment: I Think you add job id then when you try to makemigrations ask you to enter default value and you enter invalid default value that's make this error when you try to migrate.